# Micrometer metrics for Spring WebClient's OAuth2 flows

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring's `WebClient` in a non-reactive application to make requests to a third-party service that uses OAuth2 client credentials for its security.

I would like to have `http.client.requests` related metrics for the OAuth2 requests that are made, however (as best I can tell) this isn't happening because `DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient` creates its own instance of `RestTemplate` [using the constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/endpoint/DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.java#L67), instead of leveraging an injected `RestTemplateBuilder`, [which would handle the instrumentation automatically](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.supported.http-clients).

Is there a way to have these metrics surfaced by Micrometer?